# How to define 4 functions to fit these two tests (javascript/q)

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I found [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), I found in it's description, there are such demo code:

```
step1(function (value1) {
    step2(value1, function(value2) {
        step3(value2, function(value3) {
            step4(value3, function(value4) {
                // Do something with value4
                console.log("finised: " + value4)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And

```
Q.fcall(step1)
.then(step2)
.then(step3)
.then(step4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
    console.log("finished in q: " +value4);
}, function (error) {
    // Handle any error from step1 through step4
    console.log("err: " + err);
})
.end();
```

I'm wondering, how to define the 4 functions `step1/step2/step3/step4` to fit these two tests?

I tried:

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); return "abc"; };
function step2(str, callback) { console.log("step2"); return str; };
function step3(str, callback) { console.log("step3"); return str; };
function step4(str, callback) { console.log("step4"); return str; };
```

and

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); return callback("abc"); };
function step2(str, callback) { console.log("step2"); return callback(str); };
function step3(str, callback) { console.log("step3"); return callback(str); };
function step4(str, callback) { console.log("step4"); return callback(str); };
```

and hope it prints:

```
step1
step2
step3
step4
finised: abc
step1
step2
step3
step4
finised in q: abc
```

But neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return via the callback

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); callback("abc"); };
function step2(str, callback) { console.log("step2"); callback(str); };
function step3(str, callback) { console.log("step3"); callback(str); };
function step4(str, callback) { console.log("step4"); callback(str); };
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work: `step1
step2
step3
step4
finised: abc
step1
err: TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: If your callback is not a function you haven't set things up properly